# Is there an objective measure of decadence?

Tags: ancient-rome

I came across [this article about how the modern (western) world is decadent](https://itsonlychemo.wordpress.com/2020/02/17/a-list-of-ten-simple-ways-we-are-decadent-and-a-speculative-theory-about-why-it-might-not-matter/). I am not necessarily convinced by the arguments that it puts forward, but I was wondering if there is an objective measure of 'decadence' that historians can employ in order to compare different cultures or epochs? Something like the [Corruption Perceptions Index](https://www.transparency.org/en/cpi/2020#) perhaps, but covering behaviours that are considered decadent.
It is often claimed that ancient Rome became decadent and that this led to its downfall. It would be instructive to have a quantifiable measure of decadence to be able to evaluate this claim.

Comment: This appears to be a question about English, not History.

Comment: @T.E.D. I am not so sure. Historians can use objective measures to perform their analysis. Consider the work of the Economic Historian.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would even define "decadent" in a way that is objective.  In many cases, what one culture considers "decadent", another does not.

Comment: I think some societies (or at least their ruling classes) are quite consistently described as decadent by historians. E.g. in China late Qing, late Ming, most of Yuan etc. Or every ruling dynasty ever after the second ruler according to Ibn Khaldun. A measure might be how much time the ruler spends on his court vs. outside of his court.

Comment: @GorttheRobot Merriam-Webster Decadent: Marked by decay or decline. So that could include, economic decline, moral decline, political decline, social decline. There could certainly be things in there that you could apply numbers to. I wonder if any historians actually have done.

Comment: Measure?  Is there even an objective definition?

Comment: @DrMcCleod note that all of your examples are of dynasties losing power in some way (or percieved as such, in case of Ibn Khaldun). Which makes them fit the dictionary definition of the word "decadent", without any other criteria.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov Yes, I suppose that is right, but if those dynasties had had an objective measure of decadence then they might have been able to spot the problem in advance.

Comment: The article is obvious rubbish. In the first item "technological stagnation" they have deliberately excluded the area of technology where most progress is being made, and even after that ignored things like space exploration, electric cars, GPS, renewable energy, medical technology, the internet, device connectivity...

Comment: @DJClayworth There's also the fact that the absence of a large-scale application of new technologies where people can see it isn't the same as the absence of technological development.  Presumably, since the year 1970, there have been changes to the insides of airplanes and ordinary, internal-combustion automobiles, because patents expire and there have been improvements affecting safety.

Comment: Well, there are certainly measurable phenomenon that could quantify decadence, but I warn you, they are not PC :D These are number of children per person (especially in upper and middle class). prevalence of homosexuality, prevalence of prostitution and legal status of it, prevalence and legal status of abortion, willingness (again in higher classes) to do some activities for the country without much of personal gain etc ...

Comment: @rs.29 Note that homosexuality was prevalent in Sparta and infanticide was prevalent in Republican Rome.  It's hard to argue either of those societies were "decadent".   Ghengis Khan might say you're decadent for living in a house, and a Puritan might say you're decadent for dancing.  It's a classic example of something culturally driven.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yeah, I read that first bullet, then thought of the 3d printed toy sitting on my desk, the portable phone next to it, the led lamp next to that, the solar panels on the roof above it, the electric car on the other side of the wall, and wonder what the hell the author is smoking.

Comment: @GorttheRobot Well, if he was smoking something I presume he would take that as an indication of decadence...

Comment: @GorttheRobot And what happened with the Sparta and Rome ? :D Btw, homosexuality was not prevalent in Sparta when they were strongest, only at later stages when they were near the end. Child sacrifice was not prevalent in Rome during Republic, they even fought the war against Carthage because of it (among other things).

Comment: @GorttheRobot Ghengis Khan was partially right, societies that do not train their males  for combat (and pamper them)  could be considered decadent. Puritans were against lewd music as something that would increase adultery . Again, they were partially right.

Comment: @GorttheRobot Btw, one of characteristic of decadent societies is that they as a rule do not see themselves as decadent :D Otherwise they would seek a cure, but usually they remain blind till the end ;)

Comment: @Gort the Robot I think his point is perfectly sensible. If you discount major technological advances such as computers since his preferred golden age -- 1970? -- then there has indeed been no technological advances. You are just biased by your reliance on reality.

Comment: @Gort the Robot If I understand correctly, child exposure (which is only *technically* different from infanticide) was also quite widespread in ancient Greece including, again, Sparta.

Comment: I think this question is on-topic as it is asking a question about the study of history - whether any sort of "decadence" metric or quantification is accepted by or used by historians. The answer may be no, but then that is the answer - that there isn't.

Comment: Perhaps downvoters could do me the courtesy of explaining their reasons in the comments. This question has already been closed once and then reopened as it is clearly on topic as a question about the techniques of historical study.

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer:**

The only way to mesure decadence is fail. However a non-decadent society, so the two parameters are not entirely linked.

**Long Answer:**

No, because a decadent society is not well defined: it consists in two things:

- A society getting less focused on the initial values that it followed earlier
- A society that gets more and more problem (eg: corruption, etc...)

So a decadent society is a variety of criteria, and those criteria are not objective: having numerous feasts is usually considered as a sign of decadence for Roma. But is it really "bad" to have feast? Does feasts destroy societies?

Most of the time in history, a society is said to be "decadent" by historians that know that this society later failed and was destroyed or suppressed (war, pandemic, revolution...). But this is not a scientific approach of the phenomenon.